# Winapi ListView_GetItemText wrong output format

Tags: c++, listview, winapi, char, items

I'm using `ListView_GetItemText` this way:

```
int count = ListView_GetItemCount(procmon_lv); //Get Items count
wchar_t buffer[2048]; //Init buffer
ListView_GetItemText(procmon_lv, count-1, 0, buffer, 2048); //Call function
LPWSTR itemtxt = buffer; //Create LPWSTR var

stringstream s;
s << itemtxt;
MessageBoxA(NULL, s.str().c_str(), NULL, NULL);

Sleep(7000); //Sleep because this piece of code is inside a While loop
```

MessageBox function is showing this:

[image]

What I need is to get the row's entire text, but It seems I'm getting an hex string...

Comment: If you want to preserve a string, don't mash it up by using incompatible character encodings. Hint: A `std::stringstream` cannot convert from a `const wchar_t*` to an ASCII (or ANSI) string. What you get as output is the address of your buffer.

Comment: Do you appreciate that the list view window is in a different process? That's going to burn you at some point. Why don't you get the data using the API instead of hacking procmon?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What API do you mean? Procmon's command line? It's quite limited. You are right I'm trying to do some kind of "hack" because  exporting the ListView to a backing file and then convert the backing file to an XML isn't a solution for what I need. I already got the HWND for the ListView, I can interact with the items (add, remove, sort...), I just need to read the rows...

Comment: All the information can be obtained by the Windows API. Hacking that way is nasty. I think you'll need to marshal the data across the process boundary for sub items. And it probably won't work on all versions of Windows. Have a look at the code for Process Hacker.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I haven't found info about how to get Procmon's data. That's why I'm doing that "nasty" hack, as a last resource. Do you know where to find that it? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Checking it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`std::stringstream` treats a `wchar_t*` pointer as a general pointer and thus stores the value of the pointer, instead of the characters that it points at.

If you want to use `MessageBoxA`, you need to convert the `wchar_t` data to ANSI.

```
int count = ListView_GetItemCount(procmon_lv); //Get Items count
wchar_t buffer[2048] = {0}; //Init buffer
char buffer_ansi[2048 * 2] = {0};
ListView_GetItemText(procmon_lv, count-1, 0, buffer, 2048); //Call function
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, buffer, -1, buffer_ansi, sizeof(buffer_ansi), NULL, NULL);

stringstream s;
s << buffer_ansi;
MessageBoxA(NULL, s.str().c_str(), NULL, 0);
```

Update: you shouldn't use `NULL` for the forth argument of `MessageBoxA`, which isn't a pointer.

---

Update 2: instead of converting the string to ANSI, using `std::wstringstream` instead of `std::stringstream`, and call `MessageBoxW()` instead of `MessageBoxA()`.

```
int count = ListView_GetItemCount(procmon_lv); //Get Items count
wchar_t buffer[2048] = {0}; //Init buffer
ListView_GetItemText(procmon_lv, count-1, 0, buffer, 2048); //Call function

std::wstringstream s;
s << buffer;
MessageBoxW(NULL, s.str().c_str(), NULL, 0);
```

Note: you have the comment "Init buffer", so **initialize the buffer**.

---

Update 3: Or, just don't use a `std::wstringstream` at all.

```
int count = ListView_GetItemCount(procmon_lv); //Get Items count
wchar_t buffer[2048] = {0}; //Init buffer
ListView_GetItemText(procmon_lv, count-1, 0, buffer, 2048); //Call function

MessageBoxW(NULL, buffer, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: That's pretty much backwards. Since the ListView holds Unicode strings, and the Windows API uses Unicode throughout, converting to an ANSI string just so that you can call `MessageBoxA` (instead of `MessageBoxW`) may fix the immediate issue. But it is the wrong solution. Simply use a `wstringstream`.

Comment: If I use the regular function `MessageBox`, compiler throws error: Cannot make conversion from const char * to LPCSTR. That's because I'm under an ANSI environment and should use `MessageBoxA` instead, so conversion to ANSI isn't necessary. I'm getting blanks in the message after applying `WideCharToMultiByte`. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @ProtectedVoid: There is no such thing as an *"ANSI environment"* (unless you are developing for Windows 95). If you have set your compiler to use MBCS character encoding, you can simply call `MessageBoxW`. Of course, noone can guess, what character encoding your ListView uses. You are passing a `wchar_t` buffer, so we have to assume, that you know what you're doing.

Comment: Using a `stringstream` is not at all required. Piping a C-style string into it, only to call `str().c_str()` on it, to get the same C-style string back is unnecessary. Simply pass the C-style string to the WIndows API. The first code snippet converting from UTF-16 to MBCS encoding assumes, that the equivalent of a Unicode code unit is exactly 2 bytes in MBCS encoding. While true for Visual Studio this is not generally the case. You can use `WideCharToMultiByte` to report the required buffer size.

Comment: @IInspectable Really? It seems that gcc initializes the entire array in both cases. https://goo.gl/Icta5s

Comment: @IInspectable quote rom [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 8.5.2 Character arrays: "3 If there are fewer initializers than there are array elements, each element not explicitly initialized shall be
zero-initialized"

Comment: You are right, of course. In fact, it is the reason, why `wchar_t buffer[2048] = {0};` initializes the entire buffer as well. I'll remove my misleading comment.